# Jwt refresh not working with memcached cache driver

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, memcached, jwt

I'm using laravel 5.2 framework and [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth).

And in ‍‍`.env` file `CACHE_DRIVER` set to `memcached`
When i want invalidate token with below code :

```
    $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
    $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    if($token) {
        JWTAuth::setToken($token)->invalidate();
    }
```

Token not set on blacklist and not invalidate 
But when i change the `CACHE_DRIVER` parameter to `file` on `.env` . invalidate token works. 
Now how can i invalidate token with `memcached` for `CACHE_DRIVER`?

Comment: please help me friends